# Array brackets encoding in request

Tags: jquery, ajax

When posting array, for example:

```
data: {id:[1,2,3]}
```

jQuery forms data as (taken from firebug):

```
id%5B%5D=1&id%5B%5D=2&id%5B%5D=3
```

But parser on server side can't process such data.

On the other hand if I post:

```
data:'id[]=1&id[]=2&id[]=3'
```

source in firebug looks like:

```
id[]=1&id[]=2&id[]=3
```

and parser correctly forms array.

Is there any way to disable encoding of brackets in POST request?

Comment: And your server is running?

Comment: Yes, it works. We just trying to fing more confortable way to send data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume that you are using PHP.

Server side, use [urldecode](http://php.net/manual/fr/function.urldecode.php) before parsing your data

Comment: No, engine is written using C++, I can't change anything inside.

Comment: If you can't change anything server side, you are stucked. Specials chars are automatically encoded when a form is submitted.